# Issue Docker with Symfony

Tags: symfony, docker

I have installed Docker and I want to run my Symfony projects. Everything looks to be configured just fine, but I keep getting Symfony errors. On the first one, Symfony do not recognise bind and autowire services.And on the second one, I receive the following error :

"The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "UserBundle\Handler\LogoutSuccessHandler".

The strange thing is that on my other computer , the same two projects are working normally with no errors (the computer is configured with MAMP). Which makes me think that the problem is in the configuration of the docker..

I do not know how to  fix the problem so I will really appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you link more informations about your docker configuration ? (like a `docker-compose.yml` file or equivalent). Also, try to run the `symfony_requirements` script on your docker env to check all required php mods

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all of your files are within the container. The easiest way to do that in dev environments is to mount a volume with your whole project (vendors included).

You should also check file permisiones (if you version of symfony is lower than 4) clear and warmup cache.